# I have a Oneplus 2. The bluetooth and wifi stopped working. It also does not get detected when connected to my laptop. Just keeps getting charged.

Tags: connection-issues

This issue started after the phone fell in water. I had given the phone for servicing. Still no use.

Comment: Most likely there's irreparable water damage to some components inside the phone.  Who handled the service - was is official Oneplus warranty/repair department, or a 3rd-party?

Answer (score 0):

The phone has water damage and these effects are permanent.

There isn't much else I can say.